# Filter content types based on folder properties

Tags: document-library, content-type, word, properties

Given:

1. some Content Types with "categories" multi-value property (sample values are: "legal consulting", "accounting consulting");
2. some folders each one with a single value "category" property

User creates documents from Word: how could I filter the Content Types available for that folder, filtering the Content Types whose "categories" include the folder' category?

UPDATES
according to suggestions, Document Libraries are the way to go.
But are they searchable by the Word File Dialog interface?
I mean, could the user search for a specific DL by its name? (and not directly searching the document name itself)

Comment: Can we specify Content Types for a specific folder? I doubt that..

Comment: I would suggest to create different document libraries instead of folders, so you can specify content types for the library.

Comment: Thank you Arsalan, that is a way we are strongly considering. We'll end up with nearly a thousand of Doc Libraries:is it suitable for Sharepoint?

Comment: Document Library is actually a special kind of list, and you can see [Plan for software boundaries (Windows SharePoint Services)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287790.aspx) (applies to WSS 3.0); it must be better in SP 2010/2013. It suggests 2,000 lists which isn't a hard limit, but after crossing the limit performance seem to degrade.

Comment: [Boundaries for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx)